# How to access node on openweathermap data

Tags: angularjs, json

How do I grab the weather description from this json output (see screenshot below) for an angular view? I can grab the temperature like this `{{weatherdata.main.temp}}`, and the wind speed like this `{{weatherdata.wind.speed}}`, but the weather description has a slightly different prefix than the above (it has `- weather: [ - { description:` as opposed to `- main: { temp:` ) , and using `{{weatherdata.weather.description}}` doesn't render it (that extra `[ -` is confusing things). What do I need to do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Duh, it's an array, so I just used `{{weatherdata.weather[0].description}}`. It worked perfectly.